# How to minify 3 JavaScript functions in 1

Tags: javascript, function, minify

I have 3 functions like this

```
$(function() {

  // Create the dropdown base
  $("<select />").appendTo("#level-2");

  // Create default option "Go to..."


  // Populate dropdown with menu items
  $("#level-2 a").each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
       "value"   : el.attr("href"),
       "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo("#level-2 select");
  });

   // To make dropdown actually work
   // To make more unobtrusive: http://css-tricks.com/4064-unobtrusive-page-changer/
  $("#level-2 select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });

 });
```

But in second function instead `#level-2` there is `#level-3` everywhere.
And in third function is with `#level-4`
Is it possible to minify 3 functions in 1?
May be with if and else operators?

Comment: I only see a single function, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you saying that you're repeating the same function each time for three separate elements (`"#level-2"`, `"#level-3"`, and `"#level-4"`)? If so, have you tried factoring out the element name and making it a parameter to the function? Doing so, you'd actually need to call it from your code.

Comment: Yes, it is same function, operating three different elements

Comment: Based on the way this sample is written, it actually seems like you have *three* functions, operating on three different elements. The copy-pasting doesn't make them the "same", because a small change in one place doesn't affect the others. See if you can create one function that takes "x" as a parameter (ie, "level-2") and performs the appropriate operation on each level. For that matter I'd personally design this without any numerical IDs, but that's another step of JavaScript understanding.

Comment: Not with `if` statements, but with arguments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your function is written to execute as soon as the script is loaded into the page; hence, the reason you repeated yourself three times for it to work on three elements. Let's improve upon that and rewrite it so we only have to write it once and it can work on any element. We're going to factor out the important code into a separate function and call it. The name of the element we want to run the code against is written as a parameter to the function `initElement`.

```
$(function() {
  initElement("#level-2");
  initElement("#level-3");
  initElement("#level-4");

  function initElement(element) {
    $("<select />").appendTo(element);

    $(element + " a").each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      $("<option />", {
        "value" : el.attr("href"),
        "text"  : el.text()
      }).appendTo(element + " select");
    });

    $(element + " select").change(function() {
      window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });  
  }
});
```

This is not the only way to do it, but it demonstrates the fundamental idea of keeping things DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). You can make further improvements upon this. Have fun!

Comment: You're welcome. Now you should look at the rest of your code and find other ways you can implement the same idea and keep things DRY. :)